# Box selection with color picking

Tags: opengl

I already have read a lot of information about objects picking. For now I decided to stop with simple colors picking technic. I know how to implement single object picking (draw one frame and test pixel color with `glReadPixel`).

Now I cannot figure out how picking with box should work. Idea to remember coordinate where mouse down was pressed and where it was released and after it take each coordinate from box and text pixel color there looks meaningful. But how should I operate with situation when, for example, my box I have a million of objects inside of box with dimensions 20x20?

Would all objects ids be read, or, may be some objects would be missed? I everything should be fine, could some one provide working peace of code for box selection?

Comment: If it's just boxes, you're probably better of with an analytical approach than drawing a complete new frame. Maybe with an acceleration data structure such as a KD tree.

Comment: @Nico Schertler could you provide any references?

Comment: For what? [Ray-Box-Intersection](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~awilliam/box/box.pdf)?

Comment: @Nico Schertler: no, for box selection.

Comment: Create a ray from the un-projected mouse coordinates and perform ray-box intersection.

Comment: @NicoSchertler +1 for the link, will benchmark this method against the slabs intersection method by Kay and Kajiya.

Comment: Assuming you're ok with missing things smaller than a pixel, theoretically you're running into the problem of getting all unique colors / (encoded ids) within a texture subimage. That's theoretically not too difficult to just loop over, but given the size of that, I'd think it'd make sense to probably look into something like compute shaders to see if some sort of set logic writeout is possible (is it possible there?).   If it's within higher level game code or something, maybe can get away with just sampling some points (meh).

Answer (score 0):

Color coding objects for picking has a bunch of cons. Guess you are facing one of them.

- If you are using depth buffer (giving z-depth to your objects), you will only be able to reach the objects which are closest to the view. Anything below it (and at the same depth) will be masked. It can never be picked using ReadPixels.
- If the projection of your object is smaller than a pixel, then technically its not visible and effectively read pixels will never be able to pick it up.
- Translucency is a bad idea (IMO) to use with read pixels because it will mix colors and make it difficult for you to get to the right object. This depends on your color coding technique too.

Ideally speaking, in a 20 * 20 box, you should be able to pick not more than 400 objects, and that too considering that each object gets exactly one pixel.

Ray Trace or Ray-Box intersection, is a more accurate approach if you have millions of objects. However, its certainly more complicated than Color coding. It gets more complicated with complex objects unless you make simpler approximations.

Alternatively, you can use select buffer which is equally accurate and far simpler to use because its natively supported by OpenGL. It does have an overhead of and extra draw call. But you really cant go wrong with this one.

Comment: One big disadvantage of using selection mode is that it's deprecated, and not supported anymore in the OpenGL Core Profile.